# Hide empty Select Dropdown Option flippening on Click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, browser

To decrease the document size on page load im loading the options of one of my select dropdowns with ajax after click on the placeholder select dropdown which only has one options inside used as placeholder.

Unfortunately the select box shows up a small empty select options field (see GIF below) before it gets replaced with the new dropdown via ajax. Looks like default browser behaviour.

[image]

I can not disable the select box because the click event does not work. Any idea how to solve this problem?

```
    // Placeholder DIV
    <div id="testdiv">
        <label>Abholort</label>                                     
        <select autocomplete="off" id="testplaceholder">  
            <option value='0'>Suchen</option>                                   
        </select>
    </div>


    // Click event
    const t = document.getElementById('testplaceholder');
    t.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            getnsax();
        }                       
    },false);
    
    
    // Ajax Request 
    getnsax = function () {             
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/include/new-from-select.php";
            headers: {                          
            },          
            data: {                     
            },                                      
            success: function(data) {                           
                $("#testdiv").html(data);
            },
            complete: function() {                  
                $("#newsddown").focus();                                                    
            },                      
        });
    }       
    
    
    // new-from-select.php
    <div id="newdiv">
        <label>Abholort</label>                                     
        <select autocomplete="off" id="new-select">  
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            ...
        </select>
    </div>
```

Comment: _"I can not disable the select box because the click event does not work."_ - what if you simply add it to the parent div instead? (Should probably add the `once` option then, so that this executes only once, instead of re-loading the select field content on every click.)

Comment: in this case you can click outside the select field only - so does not work either

Comment: `<option value='0'>Suchen</option><option>Loading...</option>`

Comment: You gif does not show a `select` being loaded with data - it shows a [tag:select2] (or other replacement *combo-box*.   If you're using [tag:select2] then use the select2 API to load your data via ajax.  Otherwise just adding a "loading..." option so the user doesn't see an empty `select`

Comment: great catch but im not using select2 - its a custom combobox without an API so this is the way i plan to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a container which looks like a select field and onclick you can set the innerHTML to the filled select

Comment: If there is no other way to solve my problem this sould work. thx